# Add extra display mode and template for category

Tags: blocks, template, category, products, products-view

I have multiple categories with each containing a few subcategories. These subcategories then contain products.

I'd like to add a new display mode to Magento that allows the following:

When i go to Category A on the website, it needs to show separate div's for each subcategory within called Category A. Each div would then contain a list with the products linked to said subcategory.

So far i managed to add an extra display mode option to the drop-down menu called "products within blocks" which i can assign to whatever Category i like. It can also be called from view.phtml on the same way it does with the other display mode's "products only", "mixed" etc. However, the function is still empty (doesn't output a proper template enabling the multiple div's containing products).

Anyone has a clue on where to look and add a new function to output a template like this the same way Magento does with for example the "mixed" display mode?

Making the template itself isn't the problem, but how magento outputs it is (i'd like to keep the code clean).